# Удаление маркера на Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Ниже написал код который добавляет маркеры на карту Google, так же есть функция которая должна удалять маркер. Задача - надо установить маркер по клику и при следующим клику на карту, удалить старый маркер и установить новый. Не могу понять почему функция удаление маркера не срабатывает и добавляться новый маркер но старый остается

```js
var map;
var marker = Array();

function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.102023, 18.052243);

    var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        icon: 'marker.png',
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    map.addListener('click', function(e) {
        clearOverlays();
        placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
 
    });
}
function clearOverlays() {
    if (marker) {
        for (i in marker) {
            marker[i].setMap(null);
        }
        marker = [];
    }
}
function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
    map.panTo(latLng);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сидел разбирал что у чему и дописал уже готовый результат + координаты самого маркера выводит на страницу в `<inpute type='text>'`

```js
var map;
var marker;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.102023, 18.052243);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);

    map.addListener('click', function(e) {
        removeMarkers();
        placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
    });

}
function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
    var marker  = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon:"marker.png"
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    map.panTo(latLng);
    $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
    $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
}
function removeMarkers() 
{
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```